# Globbing files having single different character in filename

Tags: bash, unix, glob

I have couple of files of the format,

```
unit-a.test.one.two
unit-b.test.one.two
unit-c.test.one.two
```

and I want to move all the files to make the filename

```
unit-a.test.one.sample.two
and so on.
```

While I know that using a globbing of the type

```
unit-*
```

will match all the files, I was wondering if there is a better solution to match the filenames since this method will also incorrectly match files of the type

```
unit-1.txt
```

Which is undesirable.

Comment: `unit-*.test.one.two` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using `unit-?.test.one.two` ?